# Is the amount of hydro-electricity harvested, proportional to the number of turbines?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, renewable-energy, energy-storage

I've looked on this site and people have said that it wouldn't make more energy that it would cost to have water turbines on a water tower. But if it only takes say three pumps (I don't know what it actually takes to pump the water up, but I hope you understand my question), why not put six turbines or however many you wanted on the side where the water comes back down?

Comment: Could you add a link to where you found this?

Comment: *"this site"* What site? *"people have said"* What people? *"it wouldn't make more energy [that some economically viable threshold, I suppose]"* What wouldn't? There are a lot of references without antecedeants here. That said, I suspect you are asking about a perpetual motion machine, so the answer is *"The laws of thermodynamics"* (one of which is the Conservation of Energy in with a fake mustache).

Answer (score 1):

The system you describe, a water tower with pumps and turbines, is a version of a pumped hydro storage system.

The amount of energy stored in a pumped hydro storage system is defined by the elevation, i.e. the height that the water is lifted; multiplied by the volume of water that is lifted (assuming that the height the water will fall, is the same as the height it is lifted). It doesn't make any difference whether you use one pump or one hundred; it's only about elevation and volume. The amount of energy input will be that amount of stored energy, divided by the efficiency of the pump(s), and that will be a number greater than 0, and less than 1.

The amount of electricity you get out of a pumped hydro storage system, is defined by the elevation, multiplied by the volume of water that falls, multiplied by the efficiency of harvesting; that efficiency is also a number greater than 0 and less than 1. It doesn't make any difference whether you use one turbine or one hundred.

To get the efficiency of the whole system, in a round-trip that involves pumping, then generating, so that the water reservoirs at the end are the same as they were at the start, you divide electricity out by the energy in. The elevation and the volume cancel out in that division, leaving you with pump efficiency multiplied by harvesting efficiency. As both those numbers are strictly between 0 and 1, the product of them is also strictly between 0 and 1.

Which comes down to this: the principle of conservation of energy applies - you can't get *more* useful energy out, than you put in. Indeed, you can't even get *as much* useful energy out as you put in, you will always get less. Real-world pumped hydro storage systems tend to have overall round-trip efficiencies of around 0.75 to 0.85, i.e. 75-85%.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is if we can build a perpetual motion machine (or a machine that produces energy from nothing), which as far as we know, it is forbidden by the laws of physics. The reason why your hypothetical example would not work: if you put the turbines in parallel, you must still have that the flow rate upward must equal the flow rate downward, so, assuming no heat losses, each of the six turbines will recover only half of the energy than each of the three turbines gave (because each will receive half the flow). If you put them in series the details depend on the configuration (such as at what heights you put them).